# Dynamic Average Orders Per Day Counter By Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been having some trouble figuring this out for the last hour, I hope one of you can help me out :)

**So I have figured out the formula to calculate the average orders per day like so:**

```
{=COUNTA(A2:A7)/SUM(1/COUNTIF(A2:A7,A2:A7))}  'PRESS (CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER)'
```

**DATA:**

```
         A
1 |  ORDER DATE
2 |  12/05/2019
3 |  12/05/2019
4 |  12/05/2019
5 |  15/05/2019
6 |  16/05/2019
7 |  22/05/2019
8 |
9 |
10|
```

**RESULT:**

```
1.5
```

My formula works fine to calculate only until A7. How would I make the formula dynamic so that it can calculate future data entries until A10 and/or infinity down the A column?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cell with the last date in column A can be retrieved with,

```
index(A:A, match(1e99, A:A))
```

Put this into your formula like,

```
=COUNTA(A2:index(A:A, match(1e99, A:A)))/SUM(1/COUNTIF(A2:index(A:A, match(1e99, A:A)), A2:index(A:A, match(1e99, A:A))))
```

This is a non-volatile solution (unlike OFFSET). It will only recalculate when something that affects the formula changes; not when anything in the workbook changes.

Comment: Hey, both answers worked - So i thought it would be fair to test them out of the scope of the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try,

A2:A7  -> OFFSET(A2,,,COUNTA(A:A)-1)

```
= COUNTA(OFFSET(A2,,,COUNTA(A:A)-1))/SUM(1/COUNTIF(OFFSET(A2,,,COUNTA(A:A)-1),OFFSET(A2,,,COUNTA(A:A)-1)))
```