# Dynamic Average Orders Per Day Counter By Date - Including Today()

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I feel like this is just going to keep getting more and more complex, and this is the only place I can get real help.

Thanks to the guys that helped me on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308579/dynamic-average-orders-per-day-counter-by-date), I am now working with **this formula:**

```
{=COUNTA(A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, A:A)))/SUM(1/COUNTIF(A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, A:A)), A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, A:A))))}  'PRESS (CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER)'
```

**DATA:**

```
         A            B
1 |  ORDER DATE     TODAY
2 |  12/01/2019    =TODAY()
3 |  12/01/2019
4 |  12/01/2019
5 |  15/01/2019
6 |  16/01/2019
7 |  22/01/2019
8 |
9 |
10|
```

**RESULT:**

```
1.5
```

This formula works great, but if I don't receive an order for the next 50 days, the result will stay **1.5** until my next date entry. How would I implement **=TODAY()** into the formula, so that the result will change every day - even if I never get an order again?

Thank you

Comment: It will be the same each day, you are counting the number of entries and dividing by the number of unique.  If you add today, it will simply add another day to the total and another unique day.  This means you will change the ouput today but tomorrow and the next 50 days til you get a new one it will remain the same, because you are only changing the date and the actual date does not matter only the total number of dates and number of unique dates.

Comment: I see, I thought I was onto something :(. . Do you have any recommendations? How would I go about formulating this?

Comment: No because I have no idea what you are doing.  The output based on the inputs do not make sense to me.  To me I would want to know average number of days from the minimum to the maximum date.  Not the number of days total divided by the unique.  Then you can set the maximum to today.  `=COUNT(A:A)/(TODAY() - MIN(A:A))`.  Which will give you the average number of orders per day since the first order through today.  Not even an array formula.

Comment: Holy sh**, are you a wizard? It's so simple and works perfectly! Thank you, you absolute beast!